# Power output of a CC amplifier

Tags: power, bjt, npn, transmitter

I've been learning about electronics from the book [Electronics Fundamentals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135072956), and have just finished the chapter about BJTs. Decided to put the newly gained knowledge to use and designed the following **ASK transmitter** \w an amplifier to play around with Arduino.

[image: ASK Transmitter]

Will the transmitted power output be **~100mW** and can it be improved?

Comment: Why not simulate it and find out?

Comment: *Will the transmitted power output be ~100mW and can it be improved?* What do you mean by "improved"? If I need 100 mW and the amplifier is "improved" to 200 mW, it is not an improvement for me as I want 100 mW. "More" isn't always better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your supply voltage is 5 volts  - take note

To get 100 mW out into a 50 Ω load you need an output RMS voltage of \$\sqrt{100\text{ mW} \times 50\text { }\Omega}\$ = 2.236 volts.

This has a peak value of 3.162 volts and therefore a peak-to-peak value of 6.324 volts i.e. greater than your 5 volt supply rail.

> *Will the transmitted power output be ~100mW and can it be improved?*

No, your power output will not be 100 mW - it might reach 63 mW on a good day because that's all the voltage you can extract from a 5 volt supply without using a transformer or a larger supply voltage.

Comment: sic et simpliciter :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume to modulate the output of a crystal oscillator by switching Vcc is ideal.

Crystals have high Q and unless the design has an initial condition of stored energy that forces full-scale oscillation, the envelope will rise with a number of cycles proportional to the Q & frequency of the Crystal** which tends >> 5000.

The power may be amplified with the supply voltage of the output transistor limited by your choice of thermal cooling. The output impedance is not 50 Ohms in an emitter follower, but rather the impedance to the base / hFE. Re is needed to prevent collector current from getting starved so must be equal or smaller than load R, so that the AC coupled load cannot exceed the DC current in Re.  However the collector AC swing is up to twice the Vcc DC value, so you do not capture all the available power with this design.  Consult/ re-search RF specs if you wish to determine the performance before you design something.